# CSS Style differs in Localhost vs Machine Name

Tags: browser, coding-style, localhost

I am about to wrap up the implementation for my first ExtJS based application. But I am facing a weird issue at this point.

I am using ASP.net at the server and then ExtJS at the client. I noticed that, If I run this project from Visual Studio Debugger then it works nice, and in that case my browser URL was set to

http://localhost/MyApp/Home.aspx

But As soon as I open a new browser and hit

http://MyWorkStationName/MyApp/Home.aspx

it behaves slightly different.
For instance, some Button Shapes are not rendered properly.
[image: See this image]

Can any body give me a clue how can I debug this issue. basically how the style can be influenced by the machine name vs localhost in URL ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have an external css file? maybe there is something wrong with the path

Comment: Do you have a hard-coded CSS URL that is pointing at localhost?  Just a stab in the dark, it's hard to tell.

Comment: no, they are defined with their relative path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too had the same issue.
This is due to the compatibility issue in ie8. go to tools->compatibility View Settings 
uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility view.

In local host or when we run from VS. It is not in Compatibility mode. And works fine in ie or in FF. But as soon as we change the local host to hostname/machinename it is going to compatibility view(default setting).
Jquery drag and drop functionality was also creating some problem. when it was running in compatibility view.

Answer (score 2):

Use this first in header: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`

Comment: This may indeed be the solution, but it would also be good to explain why. (see @kirant400's answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug or IE Developer tools to debug the css ( >= IE 8 preferably if Firefox is not an option.).